# Is it possible to know how long a user has spent on a questionnaire page?

Tags: typescript, angular7, mixpanel

Let's say I have an Angular questioner app is there any way to know or see how long the user has spent on each question till user hits next button/session time out and calculate the aggregate time from start to end answering questions using MixPanel?

Comment: You could inject a service that runs a timer.